# psql filter rows on an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| year | team_name | player_name | total_points |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1992 | Magic     | Shaq        | 2000         |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1992 | Magic     | Steve Kerr  | 4000         |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1996 | Lakers    | Shaq        | 2300         |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1996 | Lakers    | Magic       | 1000         |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 2004 | Heat      | Shaq        | 3000         |
+------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to write a query to find all teams where Shaq scored the most amount of points.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT year, team, MAX(total_points) FILTER(WHERE player_name = 'Shaq'
FROM basketball
GROUP BY year, team;
```

This is obviously not correct. I think I am using FILTER incorrectly because I cant get the teams where Shaq scored the most points on that team

The correct table should only have the 3rd and last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You want a `HAVING` clause comparing the teams' yearly maximum points with Shaq's points and only keep those that match.

```
SELECT year, team, MAX(total_points)
FROM basketball
GROUP BY year, team
HAVING MAX(total_points) = MAX(total_points) FILTER (WHERE player_name = 'Shaq');
```

Answer (score 0):

Query -

```
select year, team_name,high_score from (
  select *, 
  max(total_points) over (partition by year, team_name) high_score 
  from basketball) t
where t.total_points = t.high_score
and t.player_name='Shaq'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tgQhJzTw).